# Text is blocking ability to click button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a text (legacy) ontop of a button, I cannot click the button because the text is blocking it, I have turned off raycast target on the text but it still does not work. I am in unity 2D. Thanks!

Comment: nevermind, for some reason only the bottom part of the button is clickable, the text has nothing to do with it, does anyobdy know the fix to that?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have another text or gameobject on top of button which are blocking the click event. unchecking raycast target should work. could you share your project and code?